# Using loop to create multiple pivot table from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have dataframe as below:

```
user = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','101','102','102','101','101','102','102','102'],'Country':['India','Japan','India','Brazil','Japan','UK','Austria','Japan','Singapore','UK'],'Count':[50,1,2,5,6,89,10.9,10,5,6]})
```

I am trying to create individual pivot table for every value in "User" column:

```
for u in user['User'].unique():
    pivot = pd.pivot_table(user[user['User'] == u], index=["User"]
                  ,values=["Count"]
                  ,columns=["Country"]
                  ,aggfunc= len) #len for count
```

However, it only appear for User = 102, not for other users as below:

```
User  Brazil Japan Singapore UK
102      1     2      1      1
```

My desired outcome is two separate pivot tables as below:

```
User  Brazil Japan Singapore UK
102      1     2      1      1

User  Brazil Japan Singapore UK
101      0     1      0      1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm missing India and Austria in your required result example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `groupby`:

```
dfp = user.groupby(['User', 'Country']).count().unstack().fillna(0)

#           Count                                  
# Country Austria Brazil India Japan Singapore   UK
# User                                             
# 101         1.0    0.0   2.0   1.0       0.0  1.0
# 102         0.0    1.0   0.0   2.0       1.0  1.0
```

Looping over its rows to create separate Excel-files:

```
for i in dfp.index:
    dfp.loc[i].unstack().to_excel(f'{i}.xlsx')

# Country  Austria  Brazil  India  Japan  Singapore   UK
# Count        1.0     0.0    2.0    1.0        0.0  1.0
# Country  Austria  Brazil  India  Japan  Singapore   UK
# Count        0.0     1.0    0.0    2.0        1.0  1.0
```

---

Another approach:

```
for n, g in user.groupby('User'):
    df_export = g.groupby('Country').count().drop(columns='User').T
    df_export.to_excel(f'{n}.xlsx')

# Country  Austria  India  Japan  UK
# Count          1      2      1   1
# Country  Brazil  Japan  Singapore  UK
# Count         1      2          1   1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But ultimately I want to produce two separate pivot tables/dataframes which I plan to export them into two different excel files

Comment: Yes there are in the second Approach. I'll add an example for creating different Excel-files.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look - I showed how to get separate Excel files from the first solution, too. Simply depends on if you want to have all categories in all Excelfiles, or if you want to have only the needed columns in each file.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-writing the pivot variable inside the for loop, try this

```
# declare a empty frame outside the for-loop
df = pd.DataFrame()

# inside the for loop append the pivot df to tmp df created

df = df.append(pivot) 

# then u might need to fill the missing values with 0, after the loop.
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But ultimately I want to produce two separate pivot tables which I plan to export them into two different excel files.

Comment: @rain123, in that case pandas provides a excel writer [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) which you can use to write to file inside the loop.